# boost::gregorian::date does not have `set-type` functions?

Tags: c++, date, boost, setter, gregorian-calendar

For example I have a date object:

```
boost::gregorian::date date1(2013,1,31);
```

Now I want to change the day to 1. How to set day to 1?

Comment: this documentation has an example of getting the last days of the month i'm sure you could just adjust it to start_of_month instead of end_of_month http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Date types are immutable, apart from assignment, so you need to make a new date:

```
date1 = boost::gregorian::date(date1.year(), date1.month(), 1);
```

Comment: Eventually, I have done exactly what you have written. But why not to provide setter functions?

Comment: @Narek: That would require validation on each setter. Immutable types only need validation on construction, making them simpler with less scope for bugs, so some people prefer that approach.

Comment: BTW seems it does not have `operator=` But, I guess, it could. At least your reasoning would not be violated in that case. So this code is not valid.

Comment: @Narek: They certainly are assignable, as documented [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_intro) ("In general, the date class is immutable once constructed although it **does allow assignment** from another date.") What error are you getting?

Comment: Though it says that it is assignable, there is no operator= (please see in the same document).

Comment: @Narek: The document doesn't say there's no `operator=`. It says that it "does allow assignment", which clearly means that there is one (or at least, that an assignment expression will be valid).

Comment: Ok, ok! :) I thought that it would be appropriate to wright all the supported operators in the corresponding section of this document, where some of theme are represented.